# Why my text goes out of my div when i zoom out

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

Hello everybody i'm a beginner developer and I got a problem on a part of my html page, On a image i put some text and the problem is when i zoom out the text goes out of the image and reach the bottom of the page. Is there a method to fix that problem please ?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}


.box-video {
  width: 100%;
}

#header-vid{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.text-box {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-box h1 {
  font-size: 7vw;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
}


.text-box p {
  font-size: 2.1vw;
  font-weight: 500;

}
```

```html
<section class="box-video">
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>COWZY COWZY</h1>
        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR...</p>
    </div>
    <img id="header-vid" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is not going outside of the div. What's happening is you have a `max-height: 1000px;` on your `#header-vid` which means when you resize, your background image is instructing that style to go to `1000px` which is why it is appearing the text is going outside of the div. Hence, why the body color you set appears behind the `text-box` div. Judging by the `height: 100vh;` you set, I would assume you want that image to take up the entire viewport in this section. See the changes I made below.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}


.box-video {
  width: 100%;
}

#header-vid{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.text-box {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-box h1 {
  font-size: 7vw;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
}


.text-box p {
  font-size: 2.1vw;
  font-weight: 500;

}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="box-video">
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>COWZY COWZY</h1>
        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR...</p>
    </div>
    <img id="header-vid" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080">
</section>
</body>
```